# How to get a Vizify-like data visualization UI control?

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, visualization, data-visualization

I looked over some popular frameworks like Tableau, FusionCharts, Charts.js, etc but didn't find a chart specific to my requirement. I need to visualize certain data in vizify.com or mind-map like manner i.e. one big circle at the center, an several small circles branching out. Each circle will have short text inside. It's not like a network graph where one node is connected to multiple node. It need not be interactive, but some fluid animation will be nice. 
**Platform**: Windows 8 (Windows Store) app OR the web.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could embed a web page inside of your app.  If so, I would use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/).  It is extremely powerful and flexible.  There a ton of examples on their examples page.